# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4 - Custom Views for entities (Advance Find - saved views) - where are their queries in database?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

So each CRM user has their own saved views for each entity such as Account, Manager, Fund etc. But here's the issue:

I need to delete a tab which has some form data. But if I delete the tab the views that use the information on this tab will break.

For example, if I deleted a tab called "FUNDS" then a view that I had saved as "Fund Info" would break, since the query will no longer have those fields to query from FUNDS.

With that in mind I would like to go to my database and query to see which users own which views and hopefully find the users' views and their queries for those views; ultimately to see if their views' queries use the FUNDS tab.

Is this possible? Which table does CRM store saved view queries?

For example:

```
owner id        view    query    
1                22      q1
1                45      q2
1                .   
2                .   
2                .  
3  
3  
4  
5  
6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The queries you speak of are in the UserQuery entity, however, I don't think you need to go that far. If all you're doing is removing the tab from the published form, those attributes still exist, and your users' views will not break.

Comment: The fields from the old form need to be replaced with a new tab I created if I wanted their views to work. I can't just keep their views using the old data, it's inconsistent and useless. So I need to know who uses the old form data, and change just alert them.